# CPU User time and System time on AIX

Tags: linux, unix, cpu-usage, aix, hp-ux

How can I get CPU user time and system time for each cpu on AIX. 
I know I can get this value from cat /proc/stat on a linux machine, and from pstat_getprocessor() on an HP-UX machine. Is there a way to get this same metric on an AIX machine.

```
$ cat /proc/stat
...   
cpu  23697394 7969 2744135 4505191649 2958605 190 17883 0 0
cpu0 12511394 4575 1520243 2251753159 1480624 137 10580 0 0
cpu1 11186000 3394 1223891 2253438490 1477980 53 7302 0 0
...
```

Comment: libperfstat.h is the library routine that will get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mpstat](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/mpstat.htm) is providing these metrics, either parse its output or figure out how/where does it find them.

Comment: I thought mpstat would just give me percent but not individual time metrics in cycles/milliseconds/seconds. right?

Comment: You can easily convert percents of given period of time to milliseconds, seconds or cycles, don't you ?

Comment: That is true, only if I know what is time period. I don't want to get the total user cycles, system cycles from the time system was brought up. MPSTAT without any duration/time interval. If I can get this value then I will be able to get the desired result.

Comment: You know the time period, that's the `interval` argument in seconds.

Comment: My last comment was ill formed. I meant I wanted to know the total user cycles and system cycles form the time system was brought up. If I don't pass any argument to MPSTAT that is what I get but in percentage. I understand that I can convert percent to absolute value. However to do that conversion I need the total time system has been up.

Comment: I got my answer using libperfstat library. I was able to get CPU clock ticks and count. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Then next time, make more clear in your question what you are really looking for. You question states "CPU user time and System time on AIX" for each CPU and I answered to it. I don't get why you specifically focus on clock ticks and count while they are just artifacts, what eventually matters is the percentage spent in each state.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer because may be I was unclear when I said I needed time (not percentage).